# How to run Magento 2.3 on several domain aliases, but using only one website (and one storeview)

Tags: magento2, redirect

I need to create many different magento 2.3 shops as subdomains of the main shop www.domain.com; eg shop1.domain.com, shop2.domain.com, shop3.domain.com, shop3.domain.com

All those subshops will share the exact same content, products and storeviews (content in different languages using subdirectories /en /fr /de etc) of the main domain and my goal is to not create a different magento website or magento storeview for each of such subdomains. I'll customize just some graphic of the subdomains by loading a different theme/css based on the HTTP HOST env variable.

Can you tell me how to achieve this?

I've now configured nginx so that all the subdomains are mapped to the same document root, but when now I load a.domain.com I get automatically redirected to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

In my index.php I've added the lines below before ($bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);):

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

```
    case 'shop1.domain.com':
         $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '<default_storeview_code>';
         $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
    break;

}
```

I want that if I type shop1.domain.com in the browser address bar I'm not redirected to the main url set for the storeview [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) (this is my current problem).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make necessary change in nginx settings not in magento 2 index.php file

Comment: In nginx I've all subdomains working and mapped to the same document root. The problem is that once I visit a subdomain I get redirected to the main domain (and this happens due to a magento redirect, not to nginx - verified). It doesn't seem a nginx issue. In any case, if you thing that there is something to set in nginx, what should I change?

Comment: I will provide my changes what I did. I also have multiple subdomains running on same instance.

Comment: Please view my changes for the nginx by using this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eV1IAftwnJZFpKKOO4M-jtfBzay63SC6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've checked the code and I don't see anything special, except that you're changing the index in the subdomains.

Why do you repeat the codes below in the 3 locations /ca/, /english-brand/ and /canada-brand/ ?

set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/vhosts/kefdirect.com/httpdocs/pub;  /* Sub Domain */
set $MAGE_MODE developer;

What I want to do is only having the same website to be accessible with different hostnames and having magento not doing a redirect. I think that your solution doesn't solve this problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: The way you are thinking is not possible. You can do that either by creating store or multi website

Comment: It's strange. I think there should be some trick. In the end I would just navigate the same Magento website with different http hosts (eg domain.net and domain.com) without one redirecting to the default one. I should just avoid the Magento redirect

Comment: Anybody that could help developing a small extension that avoid the redirects in case of some whitelisted http hosts?

Comment: You can do this via ready made extension

Comment: I do not know how, could you help? I've no experience customizing Magento. :/

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: I had just to change the "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to "no" and it worked. Now I've to customize Base URLs, but at least I fixed the automatic redirect